# What applications are available in Ubuntu for the automation of a radio station?

Tags: automation, internet-radio

I currently use [RadioBOSS](https://www.djsoft.net/) automation softfware for the Windows operating system. I want to move away from Windows; but, I don't think that my requirements will work in Ubuntu - RadioBOSS & Cool Edit Pro

What software can I use on Ubuntu?

Comment: Please see [https://alternativeto.net/software/radioboss/?platform=linux](https://alternativeto.net/software/radioboss/?platform=linux)

Comment: For Cool Edit, try Audacity or Ardour